# Responsive Design: Header Picture

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

I got to fix the design of the website yesterday, but know dont look good at all on the phone.

Website: www.globaltcompany.com

Im trying to make the header responsive but im not getting true.

Index head code

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
<!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <!--<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../img/GTC.png" /> -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/img/Logo_PageIcon.png" />
  <title>Global Trade Company Ltd</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" type="text/css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style_index.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style_menu.css">
  <link href="js/flexisel/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>(function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_LA/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script_general.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/flexisel/js/jquery.flexisel.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
      $(".carga-modal").fadeOut('slow');
      $('body').css('overflow', 'scroll');
    });
  </script>
</head>
```

Style_menu cc

```
.contenedor-noticia{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background: url(../img/portada_index1.jpg) no-repeat center bottom;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000;}
```

style_menu ccs @ll media code

```
@media screen and (max-width:945px) {
  .contenedor-noticias{
  width:945px;
  img{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 945px;
  }
  .title-menu-bar{
    display: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width:815px) {
  .contenedor-noticias{
  width:815px;
  img{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 815px;
  }
  }
  .navegacion{
    width: 630px;
    margin-right: 40px;
  }
  .link-menu{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
  .contenedor-noticias{
  width:800px;
    img{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  }
  }
   .btn-menu {
    display:block;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:25px;
    float: right;
    padding: 14px;
  }
  .icon-menu{
    color: #fff;
  }
  .main{
    top: 10px;
  }
  .navegacion{
    display: none;
  }

  .navegacion-drawer{
    display: block;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        left:-100%;
        position: fixed;
    padding: 0;
    top: 58px;

    background-color: rgba(15, 15, 15, 0.7);

    }
  .link-sub-menu-drawer{
    background: rgb(34, 34, 34)
  }
  .menu-general{
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgb(14, 14, 14);
    left: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
  .menu{
  display:block;
  float:none;
  border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255, .3);
  display: block;
  width: 100%;

}
.link-menu{
  text-align: left;

}

.sub-menu-drawer{
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  list-style: none;

}
.item-submenu-drawer{
  padding: 3px;
  background: rgb(23, 23, 23);
}
.link-sub-menu-drawer{
    height: 37px;
}

.menu:before{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  background: rgb(73, 186, 222);
  visibility: hidden;
}
.menu:hover:before{
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.title-menu-bar{
  display: block;
}
.text-footer{
  font-size: 14px;
}
.text-info-footer{
  font-size: 11px;
}

}

@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
  .contenedor-noticias{
  width:480px;
  img{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 480px;
  }
  }
  .text-footer{
    font-size: 11px;
  }
  .text-info-footer{
    font-size: 9px;
  }
}
```

When i access by a phone, the header picture, the picture dont looks like supose to, and i have a next problem on the page of "catalogo" for some reason the menu, is on top and not on the neat before the footer.

Any other sugestions will be appreciated :D

Comment: what are your expectations of the header picture? would you describe more or post preview image?

Comment: The expectations is that the picture on the header adjust depending of the device I have that code but isn't working how supose to

Answer (score 0):

you can use `flexBox` with `img` tag

[image]

```css
.contenedor-noticia{
  background-color: #000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

img.bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    /* depends on your image real width */
    max-width: 1050px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor-noticia">
  <img src="../img/portada_index1.jpg" class="bg">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working but the menu is not showing now LOL When i check it on my phone

Comment: Are you mean view www.globaltcompany.com on mobile phone，I don't understand about `the menu is not showing on your phone`

Comment: Sorry, when i access by a cellphone, the Menu dont show, i cant see it. But i will check first how to modified the menu, and see if i can get true, but thanks a lot for your help